# why can't I move a control within a tab in WPF designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, controls, designer

I have a ComboBox within a tab and I can change its size, skew and rotation with the mouse. However, when I want to move it around, I'm not allowed to. To change the combobox's position, I have to manually enter the coordinates in the margin fields, which is really annoying. Why can't I simply move it by dragging it with the mouse?

**UPDATE**

This actually happens only in a second tab. In the first tab I can move around controls like expected.
So I cut&pasted the tab part in my xaml file in order to change the tab order. Now, I can move around controls in the first tab (former 2nd tab) whereas I can't move controls in the 2nd tab.

Sounds like a WPF designer bug to me...

**UPDATE 2**

This is a simple test case. The TestComboBox in the 2nd tab can't be moved.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="718" Width="728" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,4" Height="639" Width="708">
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" Height="23">

            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,4" Height="639" Width="708">
                <ComboBox x:Name="TestComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,10,0,0" Width="217" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
            </Grid>

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

After changing the tab order, TestComboBox can be moved:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="718" Width="728" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" Height="23">

            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,4" Height="639" Width="708">
                <ComboBox x:Name="TestComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,10,0,0" Width="217" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
            </Grid>

        </TabItem>            
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,4" Height="639" Width="708">
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Show the xaml code you've got that shows this problem if you can.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solved it by placing the the TabControl inside a grid - see code below.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="718" Width="728" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
<Grid>    
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" Height="23">

        <Grid Margin="0,10,0,4" Height="639" Width="708">
            <ComboBox x:Name="TestComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,10,0,0" Width="217" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
        </Grid>

        </TabItem>            
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
        <Grid Margin="0,10,0,4" Height="639" Width="708">
          <ComboBox x:Name="TestComboBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,10,0,0" Width="217"       VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `</Grid>` before `</Window>`?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding a `TabControl` into a new WPF Application. I added two `TabItem` controls with a `ComboBox` in each. At first, Visual Studio allowed me to move the `ComboBox` in the first tab, but not the second.

After I moved the `ComboBox` in the second tab, it would jump back to its original position when I let go of the mouse button. On closer inspection, this was because there was a `Grid` in the first `TabItem`, but not the second... perhaps you had a similar problem?

However, after testing the code that you just added, I'm afraid to say that I don't have the same problem that you do. Perhaps you should restart Visual Studio and maybe even your computer?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while working with WPF, but i do this to "bypass" it.

Just comment the grids before the one you'll be working on.

I know that that is painfull to do when working with large projects, but it's the only way i have found.